# Blocking work log in case of certain values of a task field in JIRA

Tags: jira

How can I block work log in JIRA when some task field equals given values?
Could I use DB table for a list of that values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think out of the box JIRA can do this for you.  Work logging is set at the global level (on or off for all projects), then at the individual project level (permission to log work is granted to zero or more roles).

I think you would either want to look into a plugin like "[Tempo Timesheets](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/is.origo.jira.tempo-plugin)" which appears to allow an expression for configuring your time entry or you would need to write your own "Time Entry" type application.  Your own application (or plugin gadget for JIRA) would of course be configured to look at any field coming back for a JIRA issue and use the web API to query/update JIRA.